# Cannot use mod_status through "localhost"

Tags: apache-2.4, windows-10

I've enabled [mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) for my own use under Apache/2.4.6 in my Windows 10 development box:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Require host localhost
    Require host example
    Require host example.com
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

(`example` and `example.com` represent my Windows Active Directory host name.) I'm also using name-based virtual hosts and I have a default host that roughly looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Sites/Default/htdocs"
    FallBackResource /index.php

    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common

    <Directory "C:/Sites/Default/htdocs">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

... and works fine: any host name or IP address that's not explicitly configured displays my PHP-powered *Site does not exist* error page, including `http://localhost/`.

I can access server info successfully through any of the hosted sites or right though IP address:

```
http://some.other.site.example.org/server-status
http://127.0.0.1/server-status
```

However, using `localhost` as host name triggers a 403 Forbidden status code:

```
http://localhost/server-status
```

```
AH01753: access check of 'localhost' to /server-status failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
AH01753: access check of 'example' to /server-status failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
AH01753: access check of 'example.com' to /server-status failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Sites/Default/htdocs/server-status
```

I've tried removing `localhost` from the `ServerName` directive of my default vhost but I'm still getting *Forbidden*.

What's causing `localhost` to be an exception?

Comment: As usual, I had to ask in a forum to find the solution myself. I've shared it here in case it helps others; feel free to correct any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the syntax for the local host should be:

```
Require local
```

That might have worked without having to enter the localhost IP addresses. This feature is provided by [mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#reqlocal).

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is resolving to an IPv6 address so I need to add this:

```
Require ip ::1
```